# `mpirun -n 2 ./a.x`, the two processes was stuck by epoll_wait, why?

Tags: linux, strace, mpi

I run a mpi progrem with `mpirun -n 2  ./a.x`. However, these two processes  was stuck. And it is always get stuck and seldom(actually only once) pass through.

I find follow information by `strace` and `lsof`, and what I know is that these two processes was waiting for reading or writing(?) a same file but it is not be prepared. Then, how to find what the file is and why it is always not ready to be access?

If you have any thoughts or need anything else, just please tell me, thank you!

```
//use `strace -p  31352`  
epoll_wait(18, [], 100, 0)              = 0
epoll_wait(18, [], 100, 0)              = 0
epoll_wait(18, [], 100, 0)              = 0
<...endless>
//use `strace -p 31351` 
epoll_wait(19, [], 100, 0)              = 0
epoll_wait(19, [], 100, 0)              = 0
epoll_wait(19, [], 100, 0)              = 0
<...endless>

//use `lsof -p 31352`
pfci.x  31352 jslo   18u  a_inode               0,13         0     11815 [eventpoll]
//use `lsof -p 31351`
pfci.x  31351 jslo   19u  a_inode               0,13         0     11815 [eventpoll]
```

Comment: It's difficult to debug a piece of code that you can't see. It also seems like an issue that doesn't quite fit with the topics of this site, because I'm assuming the issue is with the code (a C program?) rather than with the manner in which you run the code or how MPI itself is interacting with the system.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for your reply. I think so that this issue arouse from my code, but I  can't find out why this happen. And I am fresh in this catagory(linux process stuck). So I wish to get help like "how to find what file the process want to access" or "the process is not want to access some files but some   lock?" or any information else I can get from the bug.